# Email verification at a later date?

Tags: email, verification

By default Wordpress has a email verification during registration which I plan to override. I want the users to try out the website before sharing their personal email ids.

Is it possible to do an email verification at a later date automatically, say 15 days after registration? It would be a sufficient time for users to get an experience of the website.

Comment: Trying a website (for which you need to login) can only be possible (imo) if you send them an activation link. For this you would need a valid email address.

The only way I could see this being achieved, is if you (manually) create a user with a certain password, a dummy email address and show the password on screen instead of mailing it.

Comment: I have been able to create dummy users without the need for email verification like adding @example.com to their unique user names. My question is - can the verification mail be sent at a later date.

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: So I had asked in another community and got a probable solution, I haven't tested it. Another function has to be created for verification and a scheduled event function has to be created. Combination of both should give the result.